# Permission denied for cd command

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-14.04, groups

I have created a group for developers, to give them access to: /var/lib/dev, a folder which already have some folders and files inside.

The commands I've introduced are:

```
$ sudo useradd -d /var/dev -M -r devmaster
```

So, `devmaster` is a new system user with primary group `devmaster`. That can be checked out with `id`:

```
$ id devmaster
uid=998(devmaster) gid=998(devmaster) groups=998(devmaster)
```

Then, I changed permissions (using `chmod`/`chown`) as follows:

```
$ cd /var
$ sudo chown -R root:devmaster dev
$ sudo chmod -R o-wrx dev
$ sudo chmod -R g+wrx dev
```

And finally (my username here is just `justme`):

```
$ sudo usermod -G devmaster justme
$ id justme
uid=1000(justme) gid=1000(justme)
groups=1000(justme),998(devmaster)

$ ls -lh
// Omitted
drwxrwx---  3 root devmaster 4,0K dic 12 19:48 dev
// Omitted
```

But if I try to go into the directory:

```
$ cd dev
-bash: cd: dev: Permission denied
```

What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you didn't restart your session after giving yourself a new group membership.  Yes, `id justme` tells you that when `justme` logs in **in future**, he'll (you'll) have group membership of `devmaster`.  But that doesn't affect his (your) **current** shell sessions, as `id -a` would have told you.

Log out and log in again, check you've acquired the new group membership with `id -a`, then see if you can `cd /var/dev` (or `/var/lib/dev`, your question is ambiguous).

Comment: Yes, that was what happend.

Answer (score 0):

The thing finally was that, although I don't really know why, I had to logout and login again to test the results, which works as except, except that:

```
$ sudo usermod -G devmaster justme
```

needed the `-a` option:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G devmaster justme
```

Because if not, the secondary groups are completly replaced by `devmaster`, instead of being concatenated with any group asigned before, and since `justme` was the original administrative account, I was out of groups sudo, adm, cdrom, plugdev and other 5 groups.

So, I wasn't capable of using `sudo`, and, since there wasn't any other user account in the system, I had to reboot the machine, restart in safe mode and open a root shell to add myself to the `sudo` group and to the other lost groups.